# How to update bokeh graph based on drop down selection?

Tags: python, pandas, bokeh

I've made a graph that shows vacuum prices over time (I have a different file that scrapes and gets the prices). I used bokeh to make this graph. I started scraping different types of vacuums (robot vs. upright) and want to add a dropdown so the view can select which vacuum category they are looking at. Here is the code I have so far:

```
import pandas as pd
import os
from bokeh.plotting import figure
from bokeh.io import show
from bokeh.palettes import Viridis3
from bokeh.models import HoverTool, Select
from bokeh.layouts import column

# not real file path
GENERAL_PATH = 'C:\\Users\\data'

def make_plot(input_category):
    p = figure(plot_width=600,
               plot_height=600,
               title='Vacuum Prices Over Time',
               x_axis_label='Date',
               y_axis_label='Price',
               x_axis_type='datetime')
    p.background_fill_color = '#f5f5f5'

    for brand, color in zip(robot_df.brand.unique(), Viridis3):
        temp1_df = df.loc[(df['brand'] == brand) & (df['category'] == input_category)]
        p.circle(temp1_df['date'], temp1_df['price'], line_color=color)
        p.line(temp1_df['date'], temp1_df['price'], line_width=3, color=color, alpha=0.8, legend_label=brand)

    p.legend.location = 'top_left'
    p.legend.click_policy = 'hide'
    return p

def update_plot(attr, old, new):
    category = vacuum_select.value
    make_plot(category)

# get the full paths to data files
filenames = os.listdir(GENERAL_PATH)
files_with_path = []
for file in filenames:
    files_with_path.append(GENERAL_PATH + '\\' + file)


# get data from each file and create dataframe
temp = []
for file in files_with_path:
    temp_df = pd.read_csv(file, encoding='ISO-8859-1', header=None)
    temp.append(temp_df)
df = pd.concat(temp, axis=0, ignore_index=True)
df.columns = ['date', 'name', 'brand', 'retailer', 'price', 'stars', 'category', 'highlights']
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'])


#create dataframes for the vacuum categories
upright_df = df[(df['category']) == 'Upright']
robot_df = df[(df['category']) == 'Robot']

#make initial plot, will be robot by default
plot = make_plot('Robot')
vacuum_select = Select(title='Vacuum Category', options=['Robot', 'Upright'], value='Robot')
vacuum_select.on_change('value', update_plot)

show(column(vacuum_select, plot))
```

Right now the on_change line is generating an error that says

```
:WARNING:bokeh.embed.util:
You are generating standalone HTML/JS output, but trying to use real Python
callbacks (i.e. with on_change or on_event). This combination cannot work.

Only JavaScript callbacks may be used with standalone output. For more
information on JavaScript callbacks with Bokeh, see:

    https://docs.bokeh.org/en/latest/docs/user_guide/interaction/callbacks.html

Alternatively, to use real Python callbacks, a Bokeh server application may
be used. For more information on building and running Bokeh applications, see:

    https://docs.bokeh.org/en/latest/docs/user_guide/server.html
```

I'm not sure how else to get the change without using on_change, and I'm also confused on what should be in the update_plot function. Thank you in advance, any help is appreciated!

Comment: Did you refer to the links? With `show`, only JavaScript callbacks are availabe, i.e. `js_on_change`, `js_on_event`. To use `on_change` you would need to make the code an application running on a Bokeh server.

Comment: I've tried both js_on_change and js_on_event and they both result in an error. I might try and use a bokeh server. Either way, I think i still need help with my update_plot function

Comment: Just to clarify, those functions on work with `CustomJS` callbacks, you can't pass them Python functions. There are lots of examples in the docs for both JS and Python (Bokeh server) interactions (in exactly the links provided in the error message)